# Невозможно записать файлы в vsftpd

Tags: debian, chmod, vsftpd

Сервер debian 8 + vsftpd

Вопрос следующий - я имею пользователя user который находится в группе user:

```
id user
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
```

И имею папку folder владельцем который является user:

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 13 user user 4096 Mar 18 05:50 folder
```

Тем не менее, на фтп (vsftpd установка по умолчанию) с учетными данными этого пользователя я не могу записать файл в эту дерикторию:

```
Ответ:  550 Permission denied.
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо в конфиге vsftpd раскомментировать строчку

```
write_enable=YES
```

и перезапустить сервис.